# Fitting data with a complex function, but requiring real parameters

Tags: fitting

I am trying to fit a complex data with a complex function, with the real fitting parameters. I was trying to put there constraints like this, but I got error:

```
FindFit[data,{1-a/(b-x^2-I*c*x),{Element[{a,b,c},Reals]}},{a,b,c},x]
```

If I remove constraints, I get in general complex parameters.

Comment: Are you `x`s complex too?

Comment: No, they are real.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works quite well:

```
k = 1 - a/(b - x^2 - I*c*x);
t = Table[{x, k /. {a -> 10, b -> 5, c -> 2}}, {x, 1, 50}];
FindFit[t, {k, (a | b | c) ∈ Reals}, {a, b, c}, x, NormFunction -> (Norm@## &)]

(* {a -> 9.99976, b -> 4.99994, c -> 1.99994} *)
```